# MySQL query adds 0 to DB yet log says otherwise?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with three columns, `| id | systemid | VendorTxCode |`.

`id = 1`,
`systemid = -1`, `VendorTxCode = 1`

I'm running the following query:

```
UPDATE core_licences SET systemid = '51' WHERE VendorTxCode = '1'
```

It works with no errors, but systemid in the table changes to `0` not 53. I opened up `mysql.log` and it looks fine:

```
110 Prepare   UPDATE core_licences SET systemid = ? WHERE VendorTxCode = ?
110 Execute   UPDATE core_licences SET systemid = '51' WHERE VendorTxCode = '1'
```

PHP is fine, not reporting any errors, and as we can see from my mysql.log file above, the query is being built and executing fine. **What would cause a table field to be updated to '0' when an update query is clearly working fine?**

The field is an `int` allowing for 30 characters. I have also tried varchar with no luck. I have also tried `i` and `s` when binding the query parameters.

Everything is fine, I'm 100% sure. It's this damn table field! I've deleted the `systemid` column and recreated it, no luck.

Comment: I've flagged this for deletion, it was an incredibly focussed user error.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fully explain your situation, but remember rather that `'1'` is not thing same as `1`, and `'51'` is not the same as `51`. You're forcing a data type conversion, and it looks like the conversion from `'1'` to `1` succeeds, so that the query matches the correct record, but somehow the conversion from `'51'` to `51` fails, such that the result is `NULL`, and MySql will treat that as a `0` if NULL is not allowed in the column.

Comment: I've allowed null in the field, but it still sets it to 0. It's a PHP query so the values, such as 1, have to be in apostrophes?

Comment: If the value is in apostrophes, that indicates to the database that it is a string type, instead of a number type. I've rarely touched php, but I know it has the ability to create queries that handle numbers correctly.